# Number of Rows Between Polarity Changes SQL

Tags: sql

I want to count the number of rows between polarity changes grouped by id in SQL. I'm thinking that there may be a clever way to use window functions to get the job done but I don't know what it is.

Consider data like this:

| id | polarity | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 12/1 |
| 1 | 1 | 12/2 |
| 1 | 0 | 12/3 |
| 1 | 0 | 12/4 |
| 1 | 1 | 12/5 |
| 2 | 0 | 12/1 |
| 2 | 0 | 12/2 |
| 2 | 0 | 12/3 |
| 2 | 1 | 12/4 |
| 2 | 0 | 12/5 |
| 2 | 0 | 12/6 |
| 2 | 0 | 12/7 |
| 2 | 1 | 12/8 |

Is there a way to count the number of rows between each change in polarity to get something like this :

| id | n |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 2 | 3 |

Comment: please add your rdbms to your tags

Comment: What's the database?

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
select id, count(*) as n
from (
  select *,
    sum(i) over(partition by id order by date) as g
  from (
    select *, case when polarity <> lag(polarity) 
                        over(partition by id order by date) 
              then 1 else 0 end as i
    from t
  ) x
) y
group by id, g
having max(polarity) = 0
```